# How can I center text inside a div element using CSS

Tags: html, css, centering

I want to center the text in paragraph elements both vertically and horizontally inside the div elements (red boxes). I'm trying to use vertical-align:middle but it's not working. Any help would be appreciated, Thanks.

http://jsfiddle.net/9NLtB/

```
.transparent-btn {
    font:bold 20px"Arial Black", Gadget, sans-serif;
    font-style:normal;
    color:#ffd324;
    background-color: rgba(255, 0, 0, .90);
    border:2px solid #000;
    text-shadow:0px -1px 1px #222222;
    box-shadow:0px 0px 12px #2e2300;
    -moz-box-shadow:0px 0px 12px #2e2300;
    -webkit-box-shadow:0px 0px 12px #2e2300;
    border-radius:15px 15px 15px 15px;
    -moz-border-radius:15px 15px 15px 15px;
    -webkit-border-radius:15px 15px 15px 15px;
    width:100px;
    height:100px;
    margin:5px;
    display:inline-block;
    position:relative;
}

.transparent-btn:active {
    cursor:pointer;
    position:relative;
    top:2px;
}

#wrapper {
    text-align:center;
}

p {
    display:inline-block;
    vertical-align:middle;
}
```

Comment: This might help you out.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2939914/vertically-align-text-in-a-div

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add a `line-height` property to your div, then specify it as `normal` in your text element.

```
.transparent-btn {
    line-height: 100px;
    text-align: center;
}


span {
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;
    line-height: normal;
}
```

And yes, this works with multiple lines of text:

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/9NLtB/12/

Answer (score 0):

You can use `line-height`:

```
p {
        display:inline-block;
        vertical-align:middle;
        line-height: 55px;
}
```

[**fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/9NLtB/3/)

Comment: What if the text is more than one line?

Comment: Then i suggest a sollution with `display:table-cell`.

Answer (score 0):

try this code

```
.transparent-btn {
    font:bold 20px"Arial Black", Gadget, sans-serif;
    font-style:normal;
    color:#ffd324;
    background-color: rgba(255, 0, 0, .90);
    border:2px solid #000;
    text-shadow:0px -1px 1px #222222;
    box-shadow:0px 0px 12px #2e2300;
    -moz-box-shadow:0px 0px 12px #2e2300;
    -webkit-box-shadow:0px 0px 12px #2e2300;
    border-radius:15px 15px 15px 15px;
    -moz-border-radius:15px 15px 15px 15px;
    -webkit-border-radius:15px 15px 15px 15px;
    width:100px;
    height:100px;
    margin:5px;
    display:inline-block;
    position:relative;
    vertical-align:top;
}

p {
        display:inline-block;
        vertical-align:middle;
    line-height: 50px;
}
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/9NLtB/6/)

Comment: What if the text is more than one line?

Comment: I also want to ask the same question. What if I have text that is two p rather than just one...

Comment: then solution with display:inline-table: and display:table-cell;

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this:

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/xzhKp/)**

On `.transparent-btn` use `display:inline-table;` and `vertical-align:top;`. Then set the CSS for p to:

```
p {
    display:table-cell;
    vertical-align:middle;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add `line-height:100px;` I've removed the p tag to understand how it works exactly.

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/9NLtB/8/

Also needed float left to align the divs

```
display:inline-block;
float:left;
```

Answer (score 0):

Solved your Problem see link [Text-Aligned](http://jsfiddle.net/9NLtB/10/)

---

This is the **most efficient** mehtod just added 2 css rules

```
vertical-align:middle;
line-height:100px;
```

and removed unnecessary `<p>` tag

---

> You can align everything horizontally and vertically! just remember add line-height same as height of container and apply vertical align middle(here your container is 100px in height so used 100px line_height simple!

---

css

---

```
 .transparent-btn {
    font:bold 20px"Arial Black", Gadget, sans-serif;
    font-style:normal;
    color:#ffd324;
    background-color: rgba(255, 0, 0, .90);
    border:2px solid #000;
    text-shadow:0px -1px 1px #222222;
    box-shadow:0px 0px 12px #2e2300;
    -moz-box-shadow:0px 0px 12px #2e2300;
    -webkit-box-shadow:0px 0px 12px #2e2300;
    border-radius:15px 15px 15px 15px;
    -moz-border-radius:15px 15px 15px 15px;
    -webkit-border-radius:15px 15px 15px 15px;
    width:100px;
    height:100px;
    margin:5px;
    display:inline-block;
    position:relative;
    vertical-align:middle;
    line-height:100px;
}
.transparent-btn:active {
    cursor:pointer;
    position:relative;
    top:2px;
}
#wrapper {
    text-align:center;
}
```

html

---

```
<div id="wrapper">
<div class="transparent-btn">text</div>
<div class="transparent-btn">text</div>
<div class="transparent-btn">text</div>
<div class="transparent-btn">text</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Ok, the solution works however what if I have more than one line of text?

Comment: yes it will work in any line of text, Enjoy. if you have any query ask

Answer (score 0):

```
p {
    line-height: 100px;
    margin: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

or use this code http://jsfiddle.net/9NLtB/11/

I added `span` and `display:table` and `display:table-cell`

Answer (score 0):

I'm noticing that in your example the buttons with text are pushed down compared to the empty ones. I am assuming that's not the desired behavior.

You can use `display: table;` on the `#wrapper` and `display: table-cell;` on the `.transparent-btn`

```
#wrapper {
    display:table;
    margin: auto;
    border-collapse: separate;
    border-spacing: 5px;
}

.transparent-btn {
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
    font:bold 20px"Arial Black", Gadget, sans-serif;
    font-style:normal;
    color:#ffd324;
    background-color: rgba(255, 0, 0, .90);
    border:2px solid #000;
    text-shadow:0px -1px 1px #222222;
    -moz-box-shadow:0px 0px 12px #2e2300;
    -webkit-box-shadow:0px 0px 12px #2e2300;
    box-shadow:0px 0px 12px #2e2300;
    -moz-border-radius:15px 15px 15px 15px;
    -webkit-border-radius:15px 15px 15px 15px;
    border-radius:15px 15px 15px 15px;
    width:100px;
    height:100px;
    text-align: center;
}

p {

}
```

Now `margin: 5px;` now longer works on `.transparent-btn` once it's set to `display: table-cell;`. So we use `border-collapse: separate;` and `border-spacing: 5px;` instead.

Also your unprefixed `border-radius` and `box-shadow` should come after the prefixed versions.

Here's the: [JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/d65Vj/)